# Stop Grails from opening a connection to the database in a Controller method

Tags: database, grails

I have a service that is communicating to another machine.  Since it's a simple Controller method Grails automatically grabs a DB connection from the pool while my controller is communicating with the other server.  I'd like to prevent it from doing that, and manually open up the database connection when I'm ready so that it doesn't suck up a connection during a long period like doing network calls.  How do I prevent Grails from automatically grabbing a connection from the pool in a controller method?

Comment: Hmm, I suspect this is because of the open session in view approach where a request immediately obtains a hibernate session to use. I'm not sure you can disable that for a specific controller or even a method within said controller. A very good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a controller it has the `Transactional` annotation on it, something like:

```
 @Transactional(readOnly=true)
 class FooController { ..
```

If you remove that annotation (and any method level annotations) then Grails will no longer connect to the database to start the transaction.

Open Session In View should not come into play since we use a lazy init approach for obtaining the connection with OSIV

Note my answer above assumes you are using a recent version of Grails (2.3.x or above)

*Updated*

For MongoDB you can disable automatically connection for all controllers by defining the following bean (which overrides the default) in `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy`:

```
 mongoPersistenceInterceptor(org.codehaus.groovy.grails.support.NullPersistentCon‌​textInterceptor)
```

However there is no way to disable on a per controller basis at the moment

Comment: What if the version is below 2.3.x? Just curious.

Comment: If is below, there is no default to read only transactions for controllers, so no transaction would be started and no connection made to the database.

Comment: So I don't have @Transactional on any of my Controllers now (I am using 2.3, but I upgraded from 2.2).  I am also using MongoDB instead of Hibernate.  Does this still work for MongoDB plugin?  Can I get it to stop opening a connection automatically for me?

Comment: Ok turning it off for the entire app would be a problem for me.  It'd be really awesome if I could do this on a per method level.  Thanks for your answer Graeme.