# Grails 3.2 - No database connection when calling controller

Tags: grails

I have a controller that doesn't need to access the database, but my understanding is that a database connection is opened when a controller is called whether or not the database needs to be accessed. Is there a way to tell Grails not to open a database connection when a specific controller is called?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop Grails from opening a connection to the database in a Controller method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454902/stop-grails-from-opening-a-connection-to-the-database-in-a-controller-method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a controller that doesn't need to access the database, but my
>   understanding is that a database connection is opened when a
>   controller is called whether or not the database needs to be accessed.

It is not the case that a database connection is opened when a controller is called whether or not the database needs to be accessed.  When connections are opened may depend on a number of factors (like whether or not you are using a connection pool) but invoking a controller action does not necessarily result in a connection being opened, so you don't need to do anything to prevent that from happening.